# Why does compiling gala from source not work unless I change how HashMap is used?

Tags: development, gala

When I grab `gala` source either from GitHub or from `apt source gala` I get version 3.3.2 and when I run `ninja` to build it I get this error:

```
../src/Background/BackgroundSource.vala:123.17-123.34: error: The name `changed' does not exist in the context of `Gee.Map.Entry<int,Gala.Background>'
                background.changed.disconnect (background_changed);
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../src/Background/BackgroundSource.vala:124.17-124.34: error: The name `destroy' does not exist in the context of `Gee.Map.Entry<int,Gala.Background>'
                background.destroy ();
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Looking closer, I change this line:

```
foreach (var background in backgrounds) {
```

To this line:

```
foreach (var background in backgrounds.values) {
```

And it compiles and works fine. But, I do not understand why this package fails to compile for me but obviously works for others and presumably the build system as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this mystery. It's related to #869 which is a fix that happened shortly after `3.3.2`.

At the time the 3.3.2 build was made the vala version itself was different, so this code compiled at the time because vala was doing some additional checks on the `foreach` iterable and doing some form of type inference. This explains why there is no version of `libgee` itself that has ever exposed the default iterable of `HashMap` to be anything but `Map.Entry`, but why the code *did* compile without this hack in the past.